# How to increase the width of Popup with the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `bootstrap` modal `popup` and in the body of it I'm displaying a `Treeview` control.

When the `text` of the node is `larger` than the width of the `popup` the text is displaying outside the popup.

How can I dynamically increase the `width` with text

**CS**

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        TreeView1.ExpandAll();
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Fruits", "Fruits"));
        TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("MangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMang0", "Mango"));
        TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Apple", "Apple"));
        TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("PineappleMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMangoMango", "Pineapple"));
        TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Orange", "Orange"));
        TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Grapes", "Grapes"));

        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Vegetables", "Vegetables"));
        TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Carrot", "Carrot"));
        TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Cauliflower", "Cauliflower"));
        TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Potato", "Potato"));
        TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Tomato", "Tomato"));
        TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Onion", "Onion"));
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openTreeview();", true);
```

}

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="Div4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog custom-class" id="modalbodyforricheditor">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="H3">Editor</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                          <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All" SelectAction="none">
                     </asp:TreeView>
                        <div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-4">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnUpdateRichTextEditor" runat="server" class="btn btn-default">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                                     </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Script**

```
function openTreeview() {
            $('#Div4').modal('show');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `width: auto;` via css while maintaining min and max width using `min-width`and `max-width`

If you don't want the text to overflow the modal while the max-width is reached, you should use `overflow-hidden`property

Comment: I have added the following `min-width: 50% ;max-width: 70%; width: auto;` to the `modal-dialog custom-class` class, this is taking the max-width irrespective of the content @sailens

Comment: You should also take a look at those children elements inside the element containing the `modal-dialog-custom-class` and see if they have any width constraints @DheerajPatnaik